# Haskell hls with Atom on MacOs: How to troubleshoot

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

I am trying to get hls running with Atom on MacOS. I did everything as directed in the documentation. hls is on the path and works if called from the command. However, I don't get hls functionality. I tried to explicitly set haskell-language-server-wrapper in the haskell Atom module, did not help.
Any hints? What could I do to troubleshoot?
Cheers, Res